# jquery updating select options not refreshing text in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm have two separate arrays. I'm trying to add them to one select list based on the choice from another select list. As usual, it works in every browser but ie.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //collection a and b are global variables set when the page loads through ajax. unimportant
  $('#divList').on('change', '#ddlOne', function () {
    $('#ddlTwo').find('option').remove();
    $(collectionAorB).each(function (i, v) {
        $('#ddlTwo').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
    $('#ddlTwo').css('width', '150px');
  });
  $('#divList').on('change', '#ddlTwo', function () {
     $('#spnResult').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

The values of the options are being properly updated but the text isn't. If I first have collection a loaded into the second select, and then load collection b and choose one of the values 'spnResult' (a span) is populated with the CORRECT value from the collection b, even though it's text is still showing the value from collection a!

Help.

Comment: Instead of `$('#spnResult').text($(this).val());` have you tried `$('#spnResult').html($(this).val());`. I don't know why, honestly, but sometimes I had issues with `.text`, and so far `.html` didn't give me any.

Comment: does it show any errors in the console window from internet explorer? press f12 to open the console window

Comment: what IE version? And what jQuery version?